# scala use same logger into class and companion object

Tags: scala, logging, log4j

I would try to log using a particular log4j  logger called URM that log into a a file into a scala class and I need to use the same logger also in the companion object:

**class**

```
class MyClass{
   ...
   val logger = Logger.getLogger("URMLogger")
   logger.info("message log")
   ....
}
```

**companion object**

```
object MyClass{
   ...
   logger.info("message log")
   ...
}
```

**Log4j.properties**

```
...
log4j.logger.URMLogger=DEBUG,URM
log4j.appender.URM=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.URM.File=target/URM.log
log4j.appender.URM.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.URM.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t [%c] - %m%n
...
```

How can I initialize once my logger and use it in both class e object companion?

Comment: Why not just reverse your logic: define the logger in the companion and import it in the class. Done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
object MyClass {
  val logger = Logger.getLogger("URMLogger")
}
class MyClass {
  import MyClass.logger
  logger.info("Here we go!")
}
```